# How do I create a Flex 3 HTTP service with variable arguments?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I need to call an HTTP service using Flex that has variable arguments.  I'm using Flash Builder 4 (Gumbo) to create the service definition, but there's no UI for variable arguments, and the subclass of `HTTPServiceWrapper` that it creates doesn't seem to support it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want to send data over get or post?

```
myService.send({parameter:"value",anotherParameter:"anotherValue"});
```